# Use Ampscript to convert state abbreviation to full state name

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, country-and-state

So the state data in our database is abbreviation but we have a client who wants to display the state dynamically in the body of the email but they want to display the full state name. I'm fairly new to Ampscript and I was able to get this code below to work correctly:

Here's the ampscript code

```
%%[
Var @StateName

IF @state == 'CA' THEN
  Set @StateName = 'California'
ENDIF
]%%
```

And this is what I add to the body of the email: `%%=v(@StateName)=%%`

Could I use this same code for all 50 states, yes. However, I wanted to know if there some easier Ampscript function that I just don't know about to convert state abbreviations to full names.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to get a data extension that contains the 2 letter abbreviation as the key and the full name in a second field.

e.g.

```
  Abbreviation       FullState
      NJ             New Jersey
      CA             California
```

From here you can just do a lookup from your email, rather than have bulky AMPScript in each email.

For example:

```
%%[
    SET @State = AttributeValue("State")

    SET @FullState = Lookup("yourStateDE", "FullState", "Abbreviation", @State)

]%%

%%=v(@FullState)=%%
```

Output (using NJ as State)

```
`New Jersey`
```

This is much more easily repeatable if needed in any future emails or Landing pages, etc.  Plus it leaves easy maintenance, so you can make the change in a single location, instead of inside every email containing that script.

Answer (score 1):

As per showing US states from their abbreviations - the only easier way I can see is by setting the `IF` and `ELSE` statements.

Source of abbreviations [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasonong/List-of-US-States/master/states.csv).

However I have done the `IF` and `ELSE` logic by using the nested **[IIF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm)** statements which is essentially the same thing but reduces the effort of writing the reptitive `ELSE`.

> Note: If the abbreviations do not match with any of the comparisons
>   then it will set the defualt value to the `@variable` from your DE. Also feel free to add and remove the logic and please make sure you match the closing brackets.

Here is the code:

```
%%[
VAR @state, @StateName

SET @state = Uppercase('State field in DE')

SET @StateName = 
IIF((@state=='AL'), 'Alabama',
IIF((@state=='AK'), 'Alaska',
IIF((@state=='AZ'), 'Arizona',
IIF((@state=='AR'), 'Arkansas',
IIF((@state=='CA'), 'California',
IIF((@state=='CO'), 'Colorado',
IIF((@state=='CT'), 'Connecticut',
IIF((@state=='DE'), 'Delaware',
IIF((@state=='DC'), 'District of Columbia',
IIF((@state=='FL'), 'Florida',
IIF((@state=='GA'), 'Georgia',
IIF((@state=='HI'), 'Hawaii',
IIF((@state=='ID'), 'Idaho',
IIF((@state=='IL'), 'Illinois',
IIF((@state=='IN'), 'Indiana',
IIF((@state=='IA'), 'Iowa',
IIF((@state=='KS'), 'Kansas',
IIF((@state=='KY'), 'Kentucky',
IIF((@state=='LA'), 'Louisiana',
IIF((@state=='ME'), 'Maine',
IIF((@state=='MT'), 'Montana',
IIF((@state=='NE'), 'Nebraska',
IIF((@state=='NV'), 'Nevada',
IIF((@state=='NH'), 'New Hampshire',
IIF((@state=='NJ'), 'New Jersey',
IIF((@state=='NM'), 'New Mexico',
IIF((@state=='NY'), 'New York',
IIF((@state=='NC'), 'North Carolina',
IIF((@state=='ND'), 'North Dakota',
IIF((@state=='OH'), 'Ohio',
IIF((@state=='OK'), 'Oklahoma',
IIF((@state=='OR'), 'Oregon',
IIF((@state=='MD'), 'Maryland',
IIF((@state=='MA'), 'Massachusetts',
IIF((@state=='MI'), 'Michigan',
IIF((@state=='MN'), 'Minnesota',
IIF((@state=='MS'), 'Mississippi',
IIF((@state=='MO'), 'Missouri',
IIF((@state=='PA'), 'Pennsylvania',
IIF((@state=='RI'), 'Rhode Island',
IIF((@state=='SC'), 'South Carolina',
IIF((@state=='SD'), 'South Dakota',
IIF((@state=='TN'), 'Tennessee',
IIF((@state=='TX'), 'Texas',
IIF((@state=='UT'), 'Utah',
IIF((@state=='VT'), 'Vermont',
IIF((@state=='VA'), 'Virginia',
IIF((@state=='WA'), 'Washington',
IIF((@state=='WV'), 'West Virginia',
IIF((@state=='WI'), 'Wisconsin',
IIF((@state=='WY'), 'Wyomingr', @state
)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
]%%
%%=v(@StateName)=%%
```